# AJAX JSONP with Jersey / JAX-RS Restful service

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest, jax-rs

I've read a lot of questions on stackoverflow but i've not got solution to my problem.

This is my Restful service:

```
@GET
@Path("/GetAllProducts")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getAllProducts() {        
    return  "{\"name\":\"MAC\", \"quantity\":\"10\"}";
}
```

It works fine on browser but when i used AJAX, it didn't display errors but showed a popup: Failed object[Object]

And my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/Restful/REST/WebService/GetAllProducts",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function() { 
        alert("Success"); 
    },
    error: function(e) { 
        alert('Failed! ' + e); 
    }
});
```

I tried to add: "crossDomain: true" but it didn't work.

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: On java you're sending a JSON object but in the ajax code you're saying that you'll receive a JSONP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let me explain some ways we could debug this..

### We could...

- Change the `error` function in the AJAX call. The first argument is actually the `jqHXR` object, not the error message. The arguments actually go `jqhxr, status, errorMsg`. So if we used the function:

  ```
  error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
      alert('Failed! ' + errorMsg);
  }
  ```

  we would see this alert:

  [image]

  Doesn't really help in this case if you don't know what it means, but sometimes it's helpful.

### We could...

- Check the server log

  In this case the server log doesn't show any errors meaning the request was processed successfully and the response was returned.

### We could...

- Use a browser development tool. For Firefox, you should install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). You can see the request and all the headers and such

[image]

You can see the request is being made with a `callback` query parameter. Also pay close attention to the `Accept` header, which reads `application/javascript`

Chrome has the same type of tool, and AFAIK, it is built in, and you can find it under Developer Tools.

### That being said..

There error comes from the `dataType` setting in your AJAX request. JSONP is not the same a JSON. JSONP is Javascript code sent back from the server that is meant to be processed by the front end. So jQuery is expecting JSONP format, that's why it set's the headers the `application/javascript` and that's why the "Syntax Error" message, as JSON format is not the same syntax as JSONP.

So to fix it, you just simply need to set the `dataType` as `json`

```
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
    alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
},
```

Now you will see a few things:

1. The Success message of course:

   [image]
2. The request is no longer being made with the `callback` query parameter, as that is only for the JSONP protocol.

   [image]
3. The `Accept` headers now use `application/json`

   [image]

---

Just an FYI, `contentType` sets the `Content-Type` header. That is only useful when we are sending information, say in a POST request.

---

## UPDATE

### Just for completeness:

I'm not sure if you *were* expecting JSONP outoup, but if you were, one thing you need to know is that JSONP support is not standard in JAX-RS. It dependends on the JAX-RS implementation, how you will need to configure the support.

**First here's how your AJAX request should change to:** (or something similar)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/Restful/REST/WebService/GetAllProducts",
    type: 'GET',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
        alert('Failed! ' + errorMsg);
    }
});
```

With JSONP, the request will look something like `url?callback=someFunctionToCall`, where `someFunctionToCall` is what the server wraps around the JSON, and is the name of the our Javascript function we want to be invoked. So the return response might look something like:

```
someFunctionToCall({"name":"MAC", "quantity":"10"})
```

With jQuery though, we don't need to send the `callback` query parameter. Its value will be made at random. When I tested, this was the request and response:

```
// request
.../GetAllProducts?callback=jQuery20302583482212586644_1418019088133
// response
jQuery20302583482212586644_1418019088133({"name":"MAC", "quantity":"10"})
```

On return of the response, our `success` function will be called, passing in the data, as would a normal response. The above AJAX request will alert the exact same message as above.

**Support for Resteasy**

With Reasteasy (3.x.x at least), we should first have the Resteasy Jackson provider

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

All we need to do is add the JSONP interceptor to our deployment

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.JacksonJsonpInterceptor
```

I haven't gotten the exact science down of which media types *need* to be added for this support, but I tested with

```
@Produces({"text/javascript","application/javascript", "application/json"})
```

**For Jersey 2.x**

Jersey comes with built in support for JSONP, so we don't need any other dependencies, from the default distribution. We just need to add the `@JSONP` annotation.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.JSONP;

@Path("/WebService")
public class ProductsResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/GetAllProducts")
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/javascript"})
    @JSONP(queryParam = "callback")
    public String getAllProducts() {
        return "{\"name\":\"MAC\", \"quantity\":\"10\"}";
    }
}
```

Using the same jQuery code as above, will give the same result. See more at [JSON with Padding Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7283)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to try your solution and tell you if it works. In fact, my server is glassfish and i'll try to use jboss too.

Comment: Glassfish uses Jersey. I will post Jersey solution in a bit. Are you in Glassfish 4.x ?

Comment: Yes, i used Glassfish 4. Thanks

Comment: And if i use dataType = "json". It'll give me this err "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: You needs to add CORS. I tested from the same origin. Is the host the same for the web page as is the server?

Comment: I'll post a CORS filter you can use for development

Comment: No, in my case, the client and the server are on different computers

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27328398/2587435). Register that filter with your application.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. It works well. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hi @peeskillet, however, it doesn't work with POST (or PUT) request. I think CORS only works with GET. Could you give me a suggestion how to use PUT request? Thanks and Happy new year !

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you think it doesn't work with PUT/POST?

Comment: Hi, because when i used PUT (or POST) with jsonp, the type of request would be converted into GET. So, always GET.

Comment: I believe JSONP should only be used with GET. You might be better off just using regular JSON request.

Comment: @peeskillet Isn't the main advantage of JSONP consist in working where CORS doesn't (for example in IE 10 in a few subtle cases and in earlier versions of IE with XDomainRequest)? I don't understand why you need both. If you need to use "crossDomain: true" (cross domain Ajax request in jquery) in the client side and CORS in the server side, why not using plain JSON with CORS instead of JSONP? The current solution doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: JSON with padding? Isn't this all about the JSON-Processing JSR, JSON-P? The hyphen makes a difference

Comment: @Amalgovinus No it's about JSON with padding.