# Why am i getting 405 Method Not Allowed while doing a POST Request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, cors

I am new to the rest services. I am trying to create a service that accepts json string from a client. I am getting 405 error when I am calling this service using JQuery. Below is the Java code for ws:

This is the way i am posting a request to JERSEY POST RESTFUL Webservice .

```
var orderinfo = {'ordersplitjson': ordersplitjson, 'customer_id': cust_id , 'homedelivery': homedelivery, 'seatnum' :seatnum , 'locationname':location_nam , 'rownum':rownum}; 
var json_data =  JSON.stringify(orderinfo);
        var ajaxcallquery = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
             data: json_data,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url:url+'/OMS/oms1/orderinsertservice',
            jsonpCallback:'jsonCallback',
            jsonp:false,
            success: function(response) 
            {
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
            alert('Failed! ' + errorMsg);
        }

        });


 public class OrdersInsertService 
{
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getData(OrderInfo order,@Context HttpServletResponse serverResponse)
    throws JSONException
            {
         serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With");
            serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60");

}
}


package com.util;

public class OrderInfo {

    String ordersplitjson;
    public String getOrdersplitjson() {
        return ordersplitjson;
    }
    public void setOrdersplitjson(String ordersplitjson) {
        this.ordersplitjson = ordersplitjson;
    }
    public String getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }
    public void setCustomer_id(String customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }
    public String getHomedelivery() {
        return homedelivery;
    }
    public void setHomedelivery(String homedelivery) {
        this.homedelivery = homedelivery;
    }
    public String getSeatnum() {
        return seatnum;
    }
    public void setSeatnum(String seatnum) {
        this.seatnum = seatnum;
    }
    public String getLocationname() {
        return locationname;
    }
    public void setLocationname(String locationname) {
        this.locationname = locationname;
    }
    public String getRownum() {
        return rownum;
    }
    public void setRownum(String rownum) {
        this.rownum = rownum;
    }
    String customer_id;

    String homedelivery;
    String seatnum;

    String locationname;
    String rownum;


}
```

Could anybody please let me know how to fix this

[image]

I am using Jersey 1 ,When i used your class its giving me a compiltion error in eclipse as hwon in picture

[image]

Comment: I just replaced jsonp to json ,i am getting   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Get rid of everything jsonp related. jsonp will automatically made to GET (hence the 405). jsonp with POST is no good.

Comment: When i modified jsonp to json No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I even modifed my code to public String getData(OrderInfo order,@Context HttpServletResponse serverResponse)
 throws JSONException
   {
   serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
      serverResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60");

Comment: 405 means GET is not allowed. That was the original problem. Now you seem to have a cors problem. First check if the method is even getting hit. Use a print statement. If not, then try and use a cors response fitler. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27328398/2587435) for the filter

Comment: I have seen the method isn't being hit .

Comment: Then use a container response filter. The question on the post is using Jersey 1, and my answer uses Jersey 2.

Comment: @peeskillet , even i am uisng jersey 1 rigth now .

Comment: Use the `CORSFilter` class in the question I linked to.

Comment: I have written a new class as you mentioned , i am getting The method filter(ContainerRequest, ContainerResponse) of type CORSFilter must 
  override a superclass method
 - implements com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter.filter

Comment: If you are using Jersey 1, use the class from the OP (original post), not the answer. The answer code is using Jersey 2

Comment: I'll post an answer. Give me second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) `dataType: 'jsonp'` should be `json`. Get rid of all the the `jsonp` related stuff. It should be json. jsonp will get automatically changed to a GET request, hence the 405 (method not allowed). Your resource method accepts POST.

(2) Problem with CORS. You need a filter to handle the pre-flight. If you are using Jersey 1, you can use this class

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request,
            ContainerResponse response) {

        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Then register it like

```
resourceConfig.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new CORSFilter());
```

With web.xml, add this

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.yourpackage.CORSFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

inside the `<servlet>` element that contains the Jersey servlet

Comment: Hi , I using Jersey 1 and when i used your class i am getting a compilation erorr in eclipse as shon in the picture in my question , could you please let me know how to ged rid of this error .

Comment: Sorry for that , its giving me - implements com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter.filter
 - The method filter(ContainerRequest, ContainerResponse) of type CORSFilter must override a superclass 
  method

Comment: I don't know I have no problems. I copied and pasted the above code from my IDE

Comment: Sorry for that i was using JDK 1.5 , redone to JDK 1.6 the error was gone . Now how do i get access to resourceConfig.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new CORSFilter()); inside my OrderInsertService class ?

Comment: Are you using web.xml or `ResourceConfig` class for the application?

Comment: Thank you very much , that cross origin error was gone , now i am getting 400 Bad Request in the Chrome degubber tools network tab

Comment: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@105a248; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.util.OrderInfo["ordersplitjson"])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68601/discussion-between-preethi-jain-and-peeskillet).

Comment: Now atleaset the service is being hit , thank you very much ,i will figure that issue .