# post json data in javascript to java rest service

Tags: json, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile, jax-rs

I am developing a phonegap application , in that I need to pass JSON data from my phonegap app to java rest service. I am using jquery mobile.

My Javscript:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
      // url: "http://domain.com/public/auth/app-login",
       url: "http://localhost:8090/CrunchifyTutorials/api/crunchifyService",
       dataType: "json",
       //data: {identity: <username from form>, password: <password from form>},
       data: str,
       success: function(data) {
        // obj = JSON.parse(data);

         alert("data" +data);

       },
       error: function(e) {
         alert('Error: ' + e.message);
       }
    });
```

My Java Rest services:

```
@Path("/")
public class CrunchifyRESTService 
{

    @POST
    @Path("/crunchifyService")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

  public Response crunchifyREST(InputStream incomingData) 
    {

        StringBuilder crunchifyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                crunchifyBuilder.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
        }

        System.out.println("Data Received: " + crunchifyBuilder.toString());

        // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
        return Response.status(200).entity(crunchifyBuilder.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

can you suggest me how to do it.

Comment: @jcesarmobile its not working. my data is not hitting to server.

Comment: are you testing on a simulator or a mobile?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I am testing in mobile.

Comment: then change "localhost" to the local IP of your computer acting as a server

Comment: @jcesarmobile tested by changing IP address of my computer. but not working out

Comment: are the phone and the computer on the same network?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yeah both are in same network .

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27351400/2587435) and then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27891034/2587435). Can't help without knowing what errors you're getting

Comment: @jcesarmobile i think there is problem at server side. Its not catching the request.

Comment: @peeskillet Its not showing any error.

Comment: Are your print statements printing out?

Comment: change the alert('Error: ' + e.message); to alert('Error: ' + JSON.strinfy(e)); and tell us the error

Comment: wait, when you said, "tried changing IP address of my computer" what do you meant by that? you have to change the url in the ajax function from url: "http://localhost:8090/CrunchifyTutorials/api/crunchifyService", to url: "http://192.168.1.XX:8090/CrunchifyTutorials/api/crunchifyService", where XX is the number assigned to your computer executing the server code

Comment: @jcesarmobile  $.ajax({
   url:' http://192.168.2.137:8090/CrunchifyTutorials/api/crunchifyService',
   data: GetAllElementsjson,
   processData: false,
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
  alert(data);
     console.log(data);
   }
 }); i changed like this

Comment: and if you go to that url from the phone browser do you get something?

Comment: @jcesarmobile now I am getting an error.  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.137:8090/CrunchifyTutorials/api/crunchifyService?%22[\n%20…%22pad1\%22,\n%20%20%20%20\%22designation\%22:%20\%2211\%22\n%20%20}\n]%22. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed acces

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Read the second link from my earlier comment. You need a filter